# Java method that multiplies a number x times by a number that increments x times

Tags: java, methods, iteration

[Example of the desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tez0.jpg)

Hello Everyone! I am quite new to Java, and I have a problem with creating one function that should count a monthly tax contribution.

I have a:

- monthly salary (annual salary divided by 14 - the amount of annual payrolls)
- int number n that represent the times that monthly salary is divided by 200

I need to create a function that will multiply monthly salary by another variable, let's call it "tax", that starts with 0 and then increments by 0.01 "n" times

I attach a photo of the desired outcome that better explains the  context.

Could anyone help me understand how can I iterate n times on a double and increase it n times with every iteration iteration?

I got stuck with the iteration here:

```
public default double pensionContribution() {
        double monthSalary = (calculateSalary() / 14);
        double n = Math.round(monthSalary / 200);
        tax = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tax= (n/100);
    
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwKgy.jpg).stack.imgur.com/UL4cO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Why the monthSalary is divided by 14??

I don't know you want to do like that

```
public default double pensionContribution() {
    double monthSalary = (calculateSalary() / 14);
    double n = Math.round(monthSalary / 200);
    double sum = 0;
    tax = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum = monthSary + monthSarly * tax;
    tax = tax + 0.01;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as, I can guess, this is what you need. Convert the integer division into double one.

```
public default double pensionContribution() {
  double monthSalary = (calculateSalary()/14);
  double n = Math.round(monthSalary/200);
  double sum= 0.0;
 
  // start loop and calculate total tax for n months
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { 
    sum += monthSalary * (n*1.0)/100; // you required to convert integer division into double
  }

  return sum;
}
```